# Find values in a table using different arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have two arrays say

```
code=['1','2','3'...upto 25000 records]

date=['2012-1-21','2013-2-23','2014-2-23'...upto 25000 records]
```

Suppose I have a model say Data having attributes code and date

I want to find the records of Data that matches the index values of both array..

Please help me out to achieve this..

Comment: `Model.where(code: code, date: date)`. Please, add an instance to your question

Comment: I have tried this one but it gives all the combinational values i.e any of the code from first array and any date of date array..